# Manipulacion de archivos .docx con C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microsoft-office

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio que posee un apartado encargado a la generación de certificados, cuya información debe ser representada en una plantilla de World cada vez que se especifique cierto Id, pero no he logrado encontrar alguna librería de visual studio que me permita interactuar con esta clase de archivos

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes Office instalado, en principio tendrás la librería Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, con la cual podrás manipular estos ficheros. Añádela como referencia a tu proyecto y listo. Si no la tuvieras, puedes instalarla a través del gestor de paquetes Nuget.